# Django Wagtail says I have -1 pages, attribute error when clicking explorer

Tags: django, wagtail

I am building a jobsite with a blog. I set up Wagtail a while ago and toyed with the basics. I then built the jobsite (as a separate app in the project with Wagtail installed) and that is up and running.

Now (a few months later) I am looking to work on the blog part of the site. When I log into the Wagtail admin, it says I have "-1 pages". When I click on the "explorer" link I get an attribute error:

```
Traceback:

File "/home/colin/Envs/matchstaff/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  42.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/colin/Envs/matchstaff/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _legacy_get_response
  249.             response = self._get_response(request)

File "/home/colin/Envs/matchstaff/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/colin/Envs/matchstaff/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/colin/Envs/matchstaff/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _cache_controlled
  43.             response = viewfunc(request, *args, **kw)

File "/home/colin/Envs/matchstaff/lib/python3.4/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailadmin/decorators.py" in decorated_view
  24.             return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/colin/Envs/matchstaff/lib/python3.4/site-packages/wagtail/wagtailadmin/views/pages.py" in index
  43.         parent_page = Page.get_first_root_node().specific

Exception Type: AttributeError at /admin/pages/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'specific'
```

Is this a data error where it is expecting a default page in the database? (I did add some test pages when I initially set up wagtail as proof of concept, though I assume that those got deleted when developing the jobsite part of the application).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check what pages still exist if you check the regular django admin (path = **/django-admin**). Most likely there is a page (under wagtailcore/pages) whose content_type is not Page (or a subclass of Page). You can change the content_type right there and you should be fine.

PS:
Also check that the **root** page is of type Page.

Edit:
I just realised it could also be that the root page is missing (if you accidentally deleted all pages), and than you should create one. That can also be done in the django admin.

Comment: Ok, I had nothing in the pages table. I can add them from there, but I am still getting the attribute error. How do i specify that it is the root page that I am adding?

Comment: The root page has following attributes: path=0001, slug=root, title=Root, depth=1, content_type=page. Also, num_child should be 0 if you have no other pages, but should not be 0 if you do have child pages

Comment: Only problem is now when I try to add a site, it asks me for a root page, but nothing appears in the list there. Any idea what i need to change there?

Comment: You can try to run the management command **python manage.py update_index**, or go to yourdomain.com/admin/pages/ and add a page there. I believe the management command should do the trick.

Comment: The update_index management command won't make any difference here - that just populates the search index (and is only needed if you're using Elasticsearch). You need to create a homepage through the Wagtail admin, and then create a site record pointing to it.